# How to clear image of any imageView with close path using Graphics Context

Tags: ios, swift, image, graphics

I am using this code clear part of image when user drag touch on screen. I have multiple images in overwriting each other. Now clear to top most layer is working fine, so part of lower image is visible. 
Now what i want to achieve is user select a close path and area of selected close path should be clear. **User can select multiple layers and select any portion to cut.**
eg if there are 8 images and user selects layer 6 to 8, then visible portion will be from layer 5 where user clear with touch.

```
func drawBrushOnLayer(fromPoint: CGPoint, toPoint: CGPoint , selected:[Int]) {               

            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(DrawImage.frame.size)

     var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
            DrawImage.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height - 50))

            context?.move(to: fromPoint)

            context?.addLine(to: toPoint)

            context?.setLineCap(.butt)

            context?.setLineWidth(BrushSize)

            context?.setBlendMode(.clear)

            context?.setShouldAntialias(false)

            UIColor.clear.set()

            context?.strokePath()

           DrawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!

            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

}
```

For now i am drawing white color on image but i need to clear slected area so lower image can be visible.

```
 func drawFill(point : CGPoint) {

        autoreleasepool{

            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height - 50))

            DrawImage .draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height - 50))

            UIColor.white.set()

            BezierPath.addLine(to: point)

             BezierPath.lineWidth = 2.0

             BezierPath .close()

            BezierPath.fill()

            let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

            context?.addPath(lassoBezier.cgPath)

            newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!

           DrawImage.image = newImage

                UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        }

 }
```

Comment: Thanks Nirav for editing and making question more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

func drawFill(point : CGPoint) {

```
    autoreleasepool{

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height - 50))

        DrawImage .draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height - 50))

        BezierPath.addLine(to: point)

         BezierPath .close()

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
         UIColor.clear.set()
        context?.addPath(lassoBezier.cgPath)
        context?.setLineCap(.square)
        context?.setBlendMode(.clear)
        context?.setShouldAntialias(false)
        context?.fillPath()
        newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!

       DrawImage.image = newImage

            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    }
```

}